# Where are user rights stored in AD LDS?

Tags: windows, user-management, user-accounts, ad-lds

I've installed an AD LDS on a Windows 7 Machine in the context of an local user (ws-cs-03\rseuser).

This user can access and administrate the AD-LDS instance.

Question:
Where is the information stored thas this user is the administrator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information about the user rights are stored in the "Naming Context" "Configuration"

[image: Connection Settings]

[image: Configuration Naming Context]